# How to return list of records using stored procedure and datareader in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, datareader

I want to return list of records using stored procedure and datareader in C#. Currently, it is giving me error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ClsHorseTracker' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Code:

```
public List<ClsHorseTracker> HorseTrackerList()
{
    clsUtilities clsUtilities = new clsUtilities();
    DataSet ds;
    List<ClsHorseTracker> clsHorseTracker = new List<ClsHorseTracker>();

    string sSQL = "exec HorseDetails";
    ds = clsUtilities.GetDataSet(sSQL);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                clsHorseTracker = new ClsHorseTracker
                    {
                        HorseName = Convert.ToString(reader["HorseName"]),
                        HorseTypeName = Convert.ToString(reader["HorseTypeName"]),
                    };
            }
        }
    }

    return clsHorseTracker;
}
```

Comment: `clsHorseTracker = new ClsHorseTracker` should be `clsHorseTracker.Add(new ClsHorseTracker(`.

Comment: `clsHorseTracker` is declared as a List but in the loop you are setting it equal to a single `ClsHorseTraker`. Maybe consider better names for variables.

Comment: Compiler message is more then enough to spot that the declared return type the function and the type of the object you are trying to return do not match. Are you sure if you did enough problem investigation before posting it here?

Comment: @mjwills, I implemented the same but it is giving me another error Message `"ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized." string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clsHorseTracker is a list of ClsHorseTracker. So you need to add new object to the list in "while" loop instead of assign an object to the list
Try this

```
public List<ClsHorseTracker> HorseTrackerList()
        {
         clsUtilities clsUtilities = new clsUtilities();
           DataSet ds;
           List<ClsHorseTracker> clsHorseTracker = new List<ClsHorseTracker>();

            string sSQL;
            sSQL = "exec HorseDetails";
            ds = clsUtilities.GetDataSet(sSQL);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        clsHorseTracker.Add(new ClsHorseTracker
                        {

                            HorseName = Convert.ToString(reader["HorseName"]),
                            HorseTypeName = Convert.ToString(reader["HorseTypeName"]),

                        });
                    }
                }


            }


            return clsHorseTracker;
        }
```

Comment: I implemented the same but it is giving me another error `Message "ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized." string`

Comment: You didn't set a connection to SqlCommand. So I think you should refer some ADO.net tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples